# Will HashMap's containsKey method in java, check for an integer if I put a character in it?

Tags: java, file-io, hashmap, filereader, randomaccessfile

Hello I wrote a small snippet of code using `HashMap` from java. My aim is to read from a file and get the frequencies of different characters in the file. For example in my file called `input.txt`, I have this text:

```
ppp-iii
```

The output should print something like this.

```
p   :   3
i   :   3
-   :   1
```

But I keep getting this

```
p   :   1
i   :   1
-   :   1
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Apples {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        RandomAccessFile fr = new RandomAccessFile("input.txt", "r");
        HashMap<Character, Integer> charFreqMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        int ch;
        while((ch = fr.read()) != -1){
            if(!charFreqMap.containsKey(ch)){
                charFreqMap.put((char)ch, 1); 
                /* I am reading an int ch, but I am adding a typecasted char ch to the
                hashmap, so maybe my hashmap is never going to else block.*/
            }
            else{
                int prev = charFreqMap.get(ch);
                charFreqMap.remove(ch);
                prev = prev + 1;
                charFreqMap.put((char)ch, prev);
            }
        }
        fr.seek(0);
        for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> kv: charFreqMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(kv.getKey()+"\t:\t"+kv.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

So I need help so that I can print the correct output wherein each character in my file gets read and it's number of occurrences (i.e., it's frequency) is printed out properly.

Comment: btw you dont have to do `charFreqMap.remove(ch);`. `Map.put` always replaces value if you put it again.

Comment: `containsKey((char) ch)` and `get((char) ch)`. An int would be boxed to an Integer, and Integers don't equal Characters.

Comment: Autoboxing works with the corresponding reference type. If you box a `char`, it will become a `Character`. If you box an `int`, it will become an `Integer`. A `Character` is never equal to an `Integer` and an `Integer` is never equal to a `Character`.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava I just added that later on while debugging thinking that it was the line of code that was the problem, but it seems it's not.

Comment: I have no idea what boxing means, but I guess this type of typecasting won't work in my case. So what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast `int` to `char` before performing any operations with a key because only `char` will be boxed to `Character`.

```
while((ch = fr.read()) != -1) {
    char c = (char) ch;
    charFreqMap.put(c, charFreqMap.containsKey(c) ? charFreqMap.get(c) + 1 : 1);
}
```

It works fine and gives the following result:

```
{p = 3, i = 3, - = 1}
```

Comment: I guess it was someone else who downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, and your example output clearly demonstrates that :)

Notice that `Map.get` and `Map.containsKey` take `Object`, not the key type, as the parameter.

When you pass an `int` variable, that is boxed to `Integer`.

If you have been putting `Character` instances into the map, none of those instances are `Integer`s. Both [`Integer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#722) and [`Character`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#2136) will only report themselves as equal to another `Integer` or `Character` respectively, even if `Character.intValue() == Integer.intValue()`.

You need to cast the parameter to a `char` in the `get` and `containsKey` calls to get it to work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now understood the difference.